# If ngSrc path is empty or gives 404 error, how to replace it with a string

Tags: angularjs

I am reading a file that contains an image path. This image path could be empty or wrong. So in case of error, **I would like to replace the image with a string, not with another image**.
I used a little trick, but I would like to know if it is correct or there is a better way to do it.

This is the snippet of the HTML/Angular code:

```
<h1><img ng-src="{{component.img || 'none'}}"  err-src><span>{{component.title}}</span></h1>
```

This is the directive I have created:

```
myApp.directive('errSrc', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {                                        
                element.bind('error', function() {
                    element.parent().addClass("no-image");
                });
            }
        };
      });
```

Initially, img is visible and span is not. Of course in the CSS file i have create a class h1.no-image that will display the span and hide the img.

Does anyone know a better way or "more Angular"-like way to realize this feature? Thanks

Comment: no need to make useless request if it is empty, can use `ng-if` for the empty case

Comment: @Malkus it is a different question. Before asking it, I looked at all the existing questions. I want to display some text instead of an another image.

Answer (score 2):

http://makandracards.com/makandra/29415-resolving-angular-not-updating-an-image-src-when-ng-src-is-empty

```
ng-src="{{component.img || '//:0'}}"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XmyLCpwJTodBrMrW2QHZ?p=preview

Comment: Slick answer!! This also works if you have an asynchronous observable that you're waiting on for a source url, e.g., `(obj | async)?.url || '//:0'`

Answer (score 0):

Try below line :

```
<img ng-src="(component.img === undefined) ? 'none' : component.img"  err-src>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use 2 `img` tags:

```
<img ng-src="{{url}}" ng-if="url_correct"/>
<img src="url_to_default_picture" ng-if="!url_correct"/>
```

So `ng-if` will insert only one tag in result html